# scala macro how to infer implicit CanBuildFrom

Tags: scala, scala-macros

```
val cbfType =
          appliedType(
            typeOf[collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[_, _, _]].typeConstructor,
            typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor :: typeOf[String] :: typeOf[List[String]] :: Nil
          )
        println(cbfType)
        val cbf = c.inferImplicitValue(cbfType)
        println(cbf)
```

I am trying to infer an implicit `CanBuildFrom`.

But the `cbf` I got is `empty tree` ?

> How can I get the implicit instance of *CanBuildFrom* in a scala macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `typeOf[List[_]]` instead of `typeOf[List[_]].typeConstructor`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/724TgGYD7Bs.